# Play Framework, Java, Apache, PostgreSQL, JPA and Hibernate for high-traffic website

Tags: java, performance, apache, hibernate, playframework

I'm gonna develop a website that will have to serve more than 300 000 users at the same time (let's say, in average 300 000 SQL requests per second) and for this website I was wondering if the following technologies are good enough to serve all these users :

- Play Framework => Java server
- Apache => front end server to load balance users redirecting them to the correct Play Framework server
- PostgreSQL with JPA and Hibernate => for the database

Do you think these technologies will be enough for this amount of users and requests ?
Do you think I will need to host the application and the database on several servers ?

Thank you for your answers !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it depends on the nature of those 300 000 SQL requests per second, but I think that you will need a lot of servers, no matter what software you use. You can get away with fewer servers if you can use some sort of NoSQL technology instead of relational databases. (For example, for Redis 100 000 requests/sec are [possible](http://redis.io/topics/benchmarks))

The good news is that once you have 300 000 users at the same time, you will also have plenty of money to hire a team of best experts, who will be able to solve your technological problems :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. And do you think I can start with the technologies I mentioned and then migrate to more powerful ones ? Also you said I'll need a lot of servers but you mean servers for the application or for the database ? Finally, is NoSQL really that good ? And can I use it with Hibernate ?

Comment: I think Java, PostgreSQL and Play Framework are fine, but if performance is critical, then I would recommend direct SQLs instead of JPA/Hibernate. NoSQL technologies can be good for performance/scalability, but also have drawbacks. Relational databases are usually easier to use, so I recommend to start with them, and migrate to NoSQL only when you really have the pleasant problem of 300 000 concurrent users :)

Comment: Thank you for your answers ! If I use Hibernate but I use some direct SQLs and I manually do some JOINS, is it ok with performances ? And you meants several servers for database or for application ?

Comment: I cannot tell exactly what is good for performance without knowing more about your app, you should ask separate questions on SO, but you should also describe what kind of SQLs, joins do you mean. I meant also multiple servers with some load balancing, you might also want to do some research on Memcached and Hadoop - these are technologies used for high-performance servers.